# Match formula on Excel not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula in Excel.

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(G1,$A$1:$A$62052,0)),"NO Match","Match")

The trouble is it only shows Match when the data matches and Match when the data does not match. What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: The sentence "The trouble is it only shows Match when they match and when they do not match" doesn't make sense. Can you please edit to make it clearer?

Comment: I meant that when the data matched it was showing Match and when the data did not match it was showing Match. The computer was just very slow though at updating the results in the cell with the formula. Thanks

Comment: You can try replacing the `$A$1:$A$62052` range with `$A:$A` or decrease the last number to the last used row

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I am getting Match and No Match but because I am dealing with large columns there was a delay in the cell updating when I changed the a data cell in the G column. The formula works. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using ISERROR?

ISERROR will return FALSE if your formula does not return an error.
So if

```
MATCH(G1,$A$1:$A$62052,0)
```

doesn't return an error, the first argument will return FALSE, and the output will be 'Match'.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you want

```
=IF(MATCH(G1, $A$1:$A$62052, 0), "NO Match", "Match")
```

Comment: "If MATCH is unsuccessful in finding a match, it returns the #N/A error value." https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

Comment: because previously when I did not get matches I would get an #N/A.